# styled-components: pass props to another component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I'm trying to build a grid component using TypeScript and styled-components. I have the following to files in a **Grid** folder:

- index.tsx
- Cell.tsx

### What I'm trying to achieve

The Grid (`index.tsx`) has a prop (`gutters`) that can be set to `margin`. I want to be able to pass this prop down to `Cell.tsx` and output different CSS if that's the case.

### index.tsx

```
import * as React from "react";
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";

import { Cell } from "./Cell";

export { default as Cell, ICellProps } from "./Cell";

export interface IGridProps {
  className?: string;
  /** Grid items */
  children: any;
  /** Grid gutters */
  gutters?: "padding" | "margin" | "none";
}

export const Grid = styled.div<IGridProps>`
  ${p => p.gutters !== "none" && css`
    margin-right: -1rem;
    margin-left: -1rem;
  `}

  ${p => p.gutters === "padding" && css`
    & > ${Cell} {
      padding-right: 1rem;
      padding-left: 1rem;      
    }
  `}

  ${p => p.gutters === "margin" && css`
    & > ${Cell} {
      margin-right: 1rem;
      margin-left: 1rem;
    }
  `}
`;

export default ({
  className,
  children,
  gutters = "none",
}: IGridProps) => (
  <Grid
    className={className}
    gutters={gutters}
  >
    {children}
  </Grid>
);
```

### Cell.tsx

```
import * as React from "react";
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";

import { IGridProps } from "./";

interface ICell {
  s: number;
  offset?: number;
}

export interface ICellProps extends IGridProps {
  className?: string;
  children: any;
  sm?: ICell;
  md?: ICell;
  lg?: ICell;
}

const calcWidth = (size: number) => `${(size / 12) * 100}%`;

export const Cell = styled.div<ICellProps>`
  flex: 0 0 auto;

  min-width: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 0;

  ${p => p.sm && css`
    @media screen and (min-width: 0) {
      margin-left: ${p.sm.offset && calcWidth(p.sm.offset)};
      width: ${p.gutters === "margin" ? `calc(${p.sm.s && calcWidth(p.sm.s)} - 2rem)` : (p.sm.s && calcWidth(p.sm.s))};
    }
  `}
`;

export default ({
  className,
  children,
  sm,
  md,
  lg,
}: ICellProps) => (
  <Cell
    className={className}
    sm={sm}
    md={md}
    lg={lg}
  >
    {children}
  </Cell>
);
```

I want to make a calculation of [the breakpoint width] - 2rem (breakpoints are defined with the `sm`, `md` and `lg` props in `Cell.tsx`). This is what I tried to achieve in `Cell.tsx` on this line:

```
width: ${p.gutters === "margin" ? `calc(${p.sm.s && calcWidth(p.sm.s)} - 2rem)` : (p.sm.s && calcWidth(p.sm.s))};
```

I know that's not how it works, but I haven't found a way of passing the props from the parent.

I've tried googling this for hours and can't find anything, so any help to get me on the right track would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Guessing you may want to use a class name which is different from default `className` like `classes`.